i got this error "The edge runtime does not support Node.js 'crypto' module." when integrating my pg db database to my nextjs 14 project using auth.js
While integrating my db for managing roles using https://authjs.dev/ i have this error:
The edge runtime does not support Node.js 'crypto' module.
my auth.ts code is:
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import PostgresAdapter from "@auth/pg-adapter"
import { Pool } from "pg"

import Google from "next-auth/providers/google"
 
const pool = new Pool({
  host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
  user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  max: 20,
  idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
  connectionTimeoutMillis: 2000,
})
 
export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
  adapter: PostgresAdapter(pool),
  providers: [Google],
})

and my middleware.ts is:
export { auth as middleware } from "@/auth";


I tried to fix the error using other databases and also a ORM, but got the same error, when i delete the integration to the db it fixes itself.

Remove export const runtime = "edge". BTW, Vercel admitted that it's not good
